# Is it possible to test a WAP site without using a mobile phone?

Tags: testing, wml

I was wondering if it was possible to do this via a browser or an emulator.

When I try it from my browser I get "Unknown file type text/vnd.wap.wml"

Thanks

Shiraz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple WAP Simulators available; an online example is [www.wapsilon.com](http://www.wapsilon.com). Google is your best friend tho :)

Comment: 2016 Update: Wapsilon closed down, domain now redirects to a typing test

Answer (score 3):

You could try one of the WAP emulators out there: [dotMobi](http://mtld.mobi/emulator.php) or [wapsilon](http://www.wapsilon.com/) for example.

**I wouldn't let it out the door without testing it in real conditions though**.

Answer (score 3):

[Opera](http://opera.com) can view WAP websites.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are quite a few WAP emulators out there.  [Here's one](http://mtld.mobi/emulator.php) I found using a search engine.

Answer (score 2):

There is also an addon for Firefox, so you can use WAP from within your browser, quite handy.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/62

Answer (score 1):

You can user simulator as you suggestion folk, but remember you should be check this on real phone because emulator not guarantee any, on the phone it can work by another way.